# Jquery-validate not working, browser freezes

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to make a registration page with bootstrap and jQuery validation. Unfortunately, when I call the .validate() function, Opera freezes for ~5sec and the validation doesn't work.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#register").validate({
    rules:{
        email:{required:true,email: true},
        password:{required:true,minlength: 6}
    },
    messages:{
        email:{
             required:"Enter your email address",
             email:"Enter valid email address"
        },
        password:{
             required:"Enter your password",
             minlength:"Password must be minimum 6 characters"
        }
    },
    errorClass: "help-inline",
    errorElement: "span",

    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
    {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass)
    {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
    }
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="register" method='post' action=''>
<fieldset>
<legend>Reg</legend>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="input-medium" id="email" name="email">
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="password" class="input-medium" id="password" name="password">
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label"></label>
<div class="controls">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Included JS files: jquery-1.8.3.min.js, bootstrap.min.js, jquery-validate.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I was using the wrong library - http://plugins.jquery.com/validate/ instead of http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/. Such a shame :/

Comment: Good thing you figured it out, because there would have been no way for any of us to see that.